# How to programmaticaly handle last visited screen persistance in appium for performing appropriate navigation while running complete suite

Tags: java, automation, appium

Problem Statement:

I'm automating an android application where it has multiple navigation menu options like 'Photos', 'Music', 'Documents' and inside this menus there are multiple screen i have to scroll through like (Photos > Photos, Timeline, Albums, Favorite).
Once i run through a test script like creating album, I'm performing app quit(), Since our app maintains last visited screen persistence i have to scroll and set the screen to default screen again which is resulting in more time for test execution and test failures some time due to improper screen positions,

Is there any way we can handle the page navigations and setting default screen in a single class and use it in other classes

Answer (score 0):

You could add capabilities so Appium performs full reset before each test clearing config cache.

```
capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", true)
capabilities.setCapability("noReset", false)
```